# How to Sync Akonadi with Google

Tags: google, akonadi

I'm trying to figure out how I can sync Akonadi (Kontact) with Google in Kubuntu 12.04. I'm looking for the akonadi-google package but I can't find a version of the deb for the 64 bit architecture. Could someone help me with this please?

When I try to build the akonadi-google package it says it can't continue ./configure without libcurl. I've installed libcurl yet I still get the same error message about libcurl being missing.

Comment: Did you try building it from [source](http://www.progdan.cz/wp-content/uploads/akonadi-google-0.3.1.tar.gz)?

Comment: Yes but libcurl is an unmet dependency. I installed libcurl but it's still saying it's an unmet dependency.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message that the build attempt gives you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Synaptic Package Manager to download and install Akonadi.  If you don't have Synaptic installed you can do so by,

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

or

[image]

Or to download Akonadi, .DEB file you can do so [from here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/akonadi-kde-resource-googledata/download)

Comment: Is this not what you were looking for?

Comment: Far from it. I never said I was missing Akonadi from my system.

Comment: But you said "I can't find a version of the deb for the 64 bit architecture."

Comment: I'm looking for the ****akonadi-google package**** but I can't find a version of the deb for the 64 bit architecture - that's what I said, that I couldn't find the akonadi-google package.

Comment: I have included the link for you, just click on the last link.  The one that says  from here

Comment: Oh you said it was a link to download Akonadi so I didn't know, LOL. I voted you up. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer both questions, but if the first works, you don't need to go the second.

1. To install it from a repository: **akonadi-google** isn't packaged (i.e., not available on Ubuntu repositores/Software Centre). The easiest way to install it is adding a third party source for the Ubuntu Software Centre. The [akonadigoogle daily builds PPA](https://code.launchpad.net/~benoitg/+archive/akonadigoogle-daily) has the package akonadi-google. Add the PPA, and then try to install it.
2. To build it from scratch: I'm currently not on Ubuntu but I'm going to guess you need an extra package like libcurl-somethingsomething-dev. Try following the insructions on [HowTo install "akonadi-google"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11373156) and check if it works.